# How to haproxy configure for multiple port

Tags: haproxy

http://example.com  ------ > X.X.X.X:80
http://example.com:8080 --------> X.X.X.X:8080

How I configure this on haproxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for

```
bind
```

in the frontend configuration (https://www.haproxy.com/blog/the-four-essential-sections-of-an-haproxy-configuration/).